$\mathbb{C}(x,f,g)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, with each pair of $\{f,g,x\}$ not generating $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$
Let $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ with total degrees $\deg_{1,1}(f),\deg_{1,1}(g) \geq 1$.
Write,
$f=a_ny^n+a_{n-1}y^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1y^1+a_0$
and
$g=b_my^m+b_{m-1}y^{m-1}+\cdots+b_1y^1+b_0$,
for some $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$, $a_i, b_j \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.
Assume that the following four conditions $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4$ are satisfied:

$C_1$: $\mathbb{C}(x,f,g)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$,
in other words, $\{x,f,g\}$ generate all $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
$C_2$: $\mathbb{C}(f,g) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
$C_3$: $\mathbb{C}(x,f) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
$C_4$: $\mathbb{C}(x,g) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

For example: $f=x+y^3, g=x+xy^2$ satisfy all 4 conditions.
More generally, $f=f_1(x)+f_2(x)y^{3+L},g=g_1(x)+g_2(x)y^{2+L}$,
$L \in \mathbb{N}$,
$f_1,f_2,g_1,g_2 \in \mathbb{C}[x]$,
each of degree $\geq 1$ is a family of $\{f,g\}$
satisfying the 4 conditions.
Questions:

(i) Is it possible to find 'all' possible forms of such $f$ and $g$? I guess that $f=f_1(x)+f_2(x)y^{3+L},g=g_1(x)+g_2(x)y^{2+L}$ was just one plausible form?


(ii) A special case, where we further assume that $y | g$, namely $b_0=0$. Perhaps it is easier to find an answer in this special case?

Non-examples:
(1) $f=(x+x^2)y, g=xf$: $C_2,C_3,C_4$ do not hold.
(2) $f=x^2y, g=x^3$: $C_2,C_3$ do not hold.
(3) $f=h(x), g=y$, where $h(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ with $\deg_x(h) \geq 2$: $C_4$ does not hold.
Asked here, slightly more elaborately, without receiving comments yet.
Thank you very much!

We can denote $t:=y^2$, then $s_1,s_2 \in \mathbb{C}[x,y^2]=\mathbb{C}[x,t]$. Then $\mathbb{C}(x,s_1,s_2)=\mathbb{C}(x,y^2)=\mathbb{C}(x,t)$.

$y^2 \in \mathbb{C}(x,y^2)=\mathbb{C}(x,s_1,s_2)$, so $y^2 \in \mathbb{C}(s_1(0,y),s_2(0,y))$.

I don't understand the relevance of $y$ and $\beta$. Why not immediately express everything in terms of $x$ and $t=y^2$?

@DaveBenson, thank you for your comment, ok, I agree and will edit the question.

Such $f,g$ can be thought of a Jacobian pair or not; I will soon calculate the Jacobian of the pair of my example.

The Jacobian of $f=f_1+f_2y^{3+L}, g=g_1+g_2y^{2+L}$ is $uy^{1+L}+vy^{2+L}+wy^{4+L}$, where $u,v,w \in \mathbb{C}[x]$; this can never be a non-zero scalar, so such $f,g$ are never a Jacobian pair.

If we allow $L=-1$ and require the Jacobian to be a non-zero scalar, then we obtain $f,g$ is an automorphic pair, linear or triangular.

You have a lot of questions along a similar theme, and, at least for the ones that I've seen, you ask for a rather technical condition without much motivation.  Could you talk about where these conditions come from?

@LSpice, thank you for your comment. I agree with you that I have a lot of similar questions to the one above and should tell about the motivation behind them. I will explain in a day or two. Thank you.

@LSpice, shortly, I am trying to find special cases in which the two-dimensional Jacobian Conjecture holds. In particular, I am considering several polynomials related to a Jacobian pair $(p,q)$, $p_xq_y-p_yq_x \in \mathbb{C}^*$. In the above question I am not considering $p$ and $q$ themselves, but polynomials $f$ and $g$ related to them, which do not have an invertible Jacobian.

Although, if $p$ and $q$ is a counterexample to the two-dimensional JC then they satisfy the four conditions, I had different polynomials in mind, with non-invertible Jacobian.

OK, thank you.  I am not the target audience, because I have no expertise, but I think that it could help your questions get more attention if you could explain in some way what sets each new question apart from the previous ones, and why the new question is the right one to ask.  (And, hopefully, to show that you have done the work to zero in on the right question yourself before asking it.)

@LSpice, thank you for your good advice. I will try to apply it from now on. Thank you.
